# Angularjs Services

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I have an table view for listing age category, and if I click create it goes to next page and I will fill thae create form and it gets saved in the table. In the table view every row has a edit button. on click of edit button it will redirect to edit page. Using services I am passing api and getting values of that perticular page in the form. on click of save button in the edit form its calling edit api and it is redirecting to table view, but value not updating. and also in the edit form i need to show age operation in select box. if operation is between then i have to show to labels for age one and age two that is also not working.I am totally confused. which is the best way to do this, Please help me in this, Thanks in advance.

my app.js code.

```
myApp.factory('ageService', function ($http, $q) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var ageGroupData = {};

    //setter for Age group
    var addAgeGroupData = function (data) {
        ageGroupData = data;
    }

    //getter for Age group
    var getAgeGroupData = function () {
        return ageGroupData;
    }


    var fetch = function (ageGroudId) {
        $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:1337/agegroup/find/',
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "id": ageGroudId
            }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            if (data.success) {

                addAgeGroupData(data);
                deferred.resolve(ageGroupData);
            } else {
                //do nothing
                console.log(data);
                deferred.reject("error");
            }
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };

    return {
        getAgeGroupData: getAgeGroupData,
        addAgeGroupData: addAgeGroupData,
        fetch: fetch
    };

});
```

Agecontroller.js code

```
$scope.fetch = function (item) {
            var ageData = ageService.fetch(item._id);
            ageData.then(function (data) {
                $scope.ageGroupData = ageService.getAgeGroupData();
                $state.go('age_edit');
            });
        }

        $scope.myData = function () {
            return ageService.getAgeGroupData().ageGroupData[0];
        };

    $scope.editItem = function (item) {
        $scope.item= item ;
        if (editForm.valid()) {
            $scope.item=item ;
            $http({
                url: 'http://localhost:1337/agegroup/update/',
                method: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    "id": $scope.item.id,
                    "ageGroupName": $scope.item.ageGroupName,
                    "operation": $scope.operation,
                    "ageLowerLimit": $scope.item.ageLowerLimit,
                    "ageUpperLimit": $scope.item.ageUpperLimit
                }),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.success) {
                    $scope.item = data;
                    $state.go('age');
                    console.log(data);
                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        }

    }
```

age edit for code.

```html
<form role="form" name="editForm" id="editForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="label1">Age Category Name</label>
        <input type="hidden" id="typeid" maxlength="100" name="typeid" value="" ng-model="item.id">
        <input name="age_category_name" id="age_category_name" class="form-control" type="text" ng-value="'{{myData().ageGroupName}}'" ng-model="item.ageGroupName" />
        <div id="chk_age_cat_name"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="label1"> Operation</label>
        <select name="operation" id="operation" class="form-control" >
            <option value="0">Select</option>
            <option ng-option selected ng-if="myData().operation== '0'" >Select</option>
            <option ng-option selected ng-if="myData().operation== '>'">Greater Than</option>
            <option ng-option selected ng-if="myData().operation== '<'">Less Than</option>
            <option ng-option selected ng-if="myData().operation== 'Between'">Between</option>
            <option ng-option selected ng-if="myData().operation== '='">Equal To</option>
            <option ng-option ng-if="myData().operation !='>'" value=">">Greater Than</option>
            <option ng-option ng-if="myData().operation !='<'" value="<">Less Than</option>
            <option ng-option ng-if="myData().operation !='Between'" value="Between">Between</option>
            <option ng-option ng-if="myData().operation !='='" value="=">Equal To</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="label1">Age</label>
        <input name="age_one" maxlength="3" id="age_one" class="form-control" type="text" ng-value="'{{myData().ageLowerLimit}}'" ng-model="item.ageLowerLimit" />
        <div id="chk_age_one"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="BETWEEN" ng-if="myData().operation=='Between'">
        <label class="label1">Age Two</label>
        <input name="age_two" maxlength="3" id="age_two" class="form-control" type="text" ng-value="'{{myData().ageUpperLimit}}'" ng-model="item.ageUpperLimit" />
        <div id="chk_age_one"></div>
    </div>

    <button name="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-success " ng-click="editItem(item)">Save</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" id="cancel" type="button" onclick='window.location.href ="#/age"'> Back </button>

    <div id="feature"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can go with angular single page application as a better solution which uses Ajax to perform all tasks

Comment: @Anandhakumar Subramaniam Thanks for your suggestion. I didin't get what exactly I have to do in my code.

Comment: Because most of the users   need to perform tasks in a single page without loading page.

Comment: I need it in different pages, so for this is there any solution..

Comment: Ok. Confirm that value is updated in dB. The page containing table view must load the values received from rest.

Comment: getting  response after save Object {success: true, updatedData: null}

Comment: for the editItem function i have to pass the edit page values, how to get that ? now item is null, some mistakes in my code..

Comment: Why updatedData is null? checked it in db whether updated or not?

Comment: its not updating in db, api is working fine,

Comment: May be problem in retrieving the ng-model values. console log it and verify items updated values.